# How to find the longest continuous subsequence whose reverse is also a subsequence

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, sequence

Suppose I have a sequence x1,x2,x3.....xn, and I want to find the longest continuous subsequence xi,xi+1,xi+2......xi+k, whose reverse is also a subsequence of the given sequence.
And if there are multiple such subsequences, then I also have to find the smallest i.

ex:- consider the sequences:

**abcdefgedcg**
here i=3 and k=2

**aabcdddd**
 here i=5, k=3

I tried looking at the original longest common subsequence problem, but that is used to compare the two sequences to find the longest common subsequence.... but here is only one sequence from which we have to find the subsequences. Please let me know what is the best way to approach this problem, to find the optimal solution.

Comment: I get i=2 k=3 for the first example and i=5 k=4 for the second.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No, you don't. Read the statement of the problem again. The definition of "k" is messed up. k is the length of the substring *minus one*, i is the *one-based* index. You are assuming that k is the length of the substring and i is the distance from the beginning, but that's not how they were defined.

Comment: @Eric: OK then. Although that works because he's guaranteed to find a substring for any non-empty input, still recommend to OP that he use normal programming conventions.

Comment: durp? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463364/substring-and-its-reverse-in-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is the longest common sub*string* problem applied to the sequence and its reverse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

This is distinct from longest common sub*sequence*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence#Substring_vs._subsequence

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The longest common substring problem compares two strings to find the common substring.... how would we apply the same principle on a single sequence and its reverse?? Please explain.

Comment: @iecut: Treat the sequence as a string and its reverse as another string. Apply the algorithm to those two strings. You may iterate backwards over the sequence to obtain the second string.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it is not longest common substring , as he is asking for subsequence , so we can apply LCS (just changing the comparison) to that it becomes MCS(minimum commom subsequence) as per question on string and reverse of string

Answer (score 2):

apply longest common substring to the string and its reverse.

```
 LCS ("abcdefgedcg", "gcdegfedcba") = "cde"
```

**EDIT**: not subsequence as potatoswatter points out, not subsequence.